# Is the average of two viscosity sub-solutions to linear elliptic equations is also a sub-solution?

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, elliptic-pde, linear-pde

Let $b\in C_b(R;R)$. Consider the following LINEAR equation on $R^2$:
\begin{equation}
    u-\partial_{xx}^2 u + (b(x+y)-b(x)) \partial_y u=f\in C^\infty_c(R^2). \tag{1} 
\end{equation}
Assume that $u_1$ and $u_2$ are two bounded sub-solutions to (1) and $|u_i(x)|\to 0$ as $|x|\to \infty$.

**My question: Is $u=(u_1+u_2)/2$ still a sub-solution to (1)?**

This point seems not easy to see from the very definition of viscosity solution. I guess some regularity assumptions on $b$ is need.